# How to refresh windows membership group without logout in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, asp.net-membership

We are using AD groups to manage roles in our website. Sometimes user groups are added/removed but it doesn't reflect in application until client re-log in to the machine. It seems that windows token does not get refreshed until log out. Is there any way to refresh windows identity roles through asp.net?

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"  enabled="true">
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Maybe, if you use kerberos for authentication. I never tried it, but you may be able to delete the kerberos Ticket Granting Ticket for the user using the klist tool from Microsoft.

Comment: Unlikely, but in principle you could change your code so that it queries the user's group memberships from AD in real time rather than querying the group membership in the user's token.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Is querying AD every time we need to check UserInRole as good practice, is there performance issues with it?

Comment: That would depend on how often you do it.  I'd recommend that you implement some form of caching, including some explicit method of flushing the cache.